# Risks associated with long-running SSH connection?

Tags: ssh

My workflow involves running Jupyter Notebook on a server, and editing & runnig code from my laptop by connecting using `ssh -L` to that server.

Recently, I made this systemd unit that maintains an always-on ssh tunnel to the big server. The information I work with is sensitive, and I wonder if there are any security risks associated with doing so?

PS: my systemd unit is pushed to https://github.com/renxida/labtunnel

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do yourself a favor and setup version control.

Comment: Just make sure that you're not supporting/using deprecated ciphers. Some weak ciphers can lead to the (partial) decryption of traffic. Some attacks require a large amount of data, so leaving an SSH-tunnel open and constantly transferring data might help into a successful attack. Take a look at for example: https://sweet32.info/
Keep in mind that an attacker will need to acquire a Mitm position first. IMHO the probability that this happens is extremely LOW. The impact depends highly on what kind of code/stuff you're doing. Risk == probability * impact.

Comment: @HamZa I believe OpenSSH at least will automatically rekey the connection for any ciphers with 64-bit blocks long before the birthday bound becomes relevant. Also, I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate, but I can't find a link to the dup. Also, [related](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/186655/165253).

Comment: @ConorMancone Thanks for the tip! I do already have version control. What I'm actually doing is that I'm using Jupyter to write and test code snippets, and then using %%writefile to generate python files to commit them.

Comment: @forest If a duplicate isn't obvious, then it's not a duplicate ; ) amiright?